# Angular 5 http.post formdata and process result

Tags: angular

I'm facing an issue with my Angular application right now. I would like to send formdata to my php api endpoint using a http.post action. This works, because it does post data to my php api endpoint.

But somehow it does not return the correct data, which is needed in another component.

The component that executes the http.post function:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataDevicesService } from '../data-devices.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  //authenticationKey: any = [];
  authenticationKey: string;
  authenticationToken: any = [];
  authenticationUrl = 'http://192.168.33.10/fortimanager/v1/api.php?login=authenticate';
  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authentication: AuthenticationService) { }

  @Input() title: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.authenticationKey = null;
    this.executeAuthentication();
  }

  executeAuthentication() {
    this.http.post(this.authenticationUrl, this.authenticationKey, {headers: this.headers}).subscribe(
      res => this.authenticationToken = res);
  }

  executeTest() {
    return this.executeAuthentication();
  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    this.authenticationKey = "key=" + f.value["key"];
    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE AUTHENTICATION TOKEN, LOGIC COMES HERE
    this.executeAuthentication();
    this.authentication.setToken(this.authenticationToken);
    console.log(this.authentication.getToken());
    $('#authenticateModal').modal('hide');
    //location.reload();
  }
}
```

The PHP api endpoint (which is very simple, just for test purpose):

```
if ($_GET['login'] == 'authenticate'){
  if ($_POST['key'] == 'abcd') {
    echo '{ "token": "123456" }';
  } else {
    echo '{ "token": "failure" }';
  }
```

And the service which will process the return of the api endpoint to other components:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  verifiedToken: string;

  constructor() { }

  getToken() {
    return this.verifiedToken;
  }

  setToken(receivedToken) {
    this.verifiedToken = receivedToken;
  }

}
```

The output the api endpoint passes back is {token: "failure"} which is not OK.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: And HTTP request is **asynchronous**. The line `this.authentication.setToken(this.authenticationToken);`is executed immediately after you sent the request. At this time, the response has not come back yet, and the callback `res => this.authenticationToken = res` hasn't been executed yet. This is being asked twice a day. Read up on asynchronism.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
async onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    this.authenticationKey = "key=" + f.value["key"];
    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE AUTHENTICATION TOKEN, LOGIC COMES HERE
    await this.executeAuthentication();
    this.authentication.setToken(this.authenticationToken);
    console.log(this.authentication.getToken());
    $('#authenticateModal').modal('hide');
   //location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code with above. But console.log(this.authenticationToken) still shows a failure. But if I change the http.pots function into res => console.log(res)); it does show the right result. Why?

Comment: use return inside executeAuthentication i.e. return this.http.post.....

Comment: Try to create a https://stackblitz.com for the same. Let me try to help